# JQuery/AJAX select text in newly added input box problem

Tags: jquery

I am creating an AJAX application. When a user selects a button a new input element is added to the web page and filled with data.  After the new input box is added (id = 'Input_thingy') to the web page I would like to select the text.  The problem I am having is that the text in the new input box is selected for only a brief moment.  This is all occurring during context of the execution of JQuery's "ajax" command:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "DoSomething.php",
    data: info,
    success: function(data) 
        {
        $('#Input_thingy').select();
            return false;
        },
 });
```

I suspect that the problem has to do with the fact that the selection command occurs in the ajax command area, but I am at a loss as to how do this correctly.  Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but perhaps the new input is losing focus when you return false. Have you considered putting the select statement on a timer like so:

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#Input_thingy').select(); }, 100);
```

This will wait until 100 milliseconds after the success to fire the text selection.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using just the $.post() function

```
$.post("DoSomething.php",
        { SomeDataToPost: "put data here"},
        function(data){
            $('#Input_thingy').focus().select();
       });
```

Comment: I am using the full functionality of the ajax command.  I just showed the part with the problem.